# Statement from ISO standard $3.1 : 1st point from n3242 doc

Tags: c++, c++11

Statement from ISO standard $3.1 : 1st point

n3242 Says:

> A declaration (Clause 7) may
>   introduce one or more names into a
>   translation  unit or redeclare names
>   introduced by previous declarations.
>   If so, the   declaration specifies the
>   interpretation and attributes of these
>   names.   A declaration may also have
>   effects including:
>       — a static assertion (Clause 7),
>       — controlling template instantiation (14.7.2),
>       — use of attributes (Clause 7), and
>       — nothing (in the case of an empty-declaration).

ISO 2003 DOC  says:

> A declaration (clause 7) introduces
>   names into a translation unit or
>   redeclares names introduced by
>   previous declarations. A declaration
>   specifies the interpretation and
>   attributes of these names.

can any one explain what is the difference .

They said  "A declaration may also have effects including: " ...CAn any one explain what are these effects in terms of Programming

Please explain these effects in Programming way(with an example program)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it just that some new features have changed the way a declaration works - in the small details.

For example, this does't just introduce some names, but also affects compilation of the code.

```
struct A
{
  int x;
};

struct B
{
    A  a;
    static_assert(sizeof(a) > 10, "Wrong member size");
};
```

We also have the empty declaration <strike>(which I belive can only be used inside a class)</strike>:

```
struct C
{
  void f()
  { };      // Semicolon here is allowed, but is an empty declaration
};
```

The empty declaration is a declaration that does **not** introduce a name (because it is empty).

Figured out the "affects template instantiation" as well, I think:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
   // some members
};

extern template class X<int>;
extern template class X<char>;
```

Tells the compiler that `X<int>` and `X<char>` will be instantiated somewhere else and does not have to be generated here.

Comment: Persson : thanks for ur answer .IN case of controlling template instantiation..how it effets ?

Comment: An empty declaration can appear anywhere.  The C++ grammar has always had a special rule which allowed an optional semicolon at the end of a function in a class; the empty declaration is a means of generalizing this.  (The latest draft I have here shows that they still have empty expression statements as well---I would have thought that the empty declaration subsumed this, and made it unnecessary.)

Comment: @James in fact, at the madrid meeting, we would have nearly shipped a standard that would allow you to have "empty-declaration" in a constexpr function body. Of course, what we wanted to ship is "null statement" or "empty expression statement". Good that we fixed this in time (last minute change), but this shows you are not alone with thinking this way :)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub:can u explain it with an example ..please

Comment: This would have been a necessary change even in C++03: In C++03 there are also some declarations that don't introduce any names into a program. Example: `struct A { A() { }` - a destructor doesn't add a member name. Example: `struct A { void f(); }; struct B : A { using A::f; void f(); }` - the using declaration doesn't add a new member name to `B`. A third case is supplied by C++0x's constructor inheritance, which may be a "noop declaration" too, last time I checked.

Comment: @1User Give up! He always mystifies his explanations.